# Recommended books for calculations in hydraulic and pneumatic systems

Tags: hydraulics

I'm starting to learn about hydraulic and pneumatic systems. Although I have some idea of the basics, I would to dive deeper into the field.

Are there any books on hydraulic or pneumatic systems, starting from basic principles and moving into calculations and other advanced topics?

Comment: A whole set, beginning to advanced, by Mannesman Rexroth Sigma. Probably difficult to find but absolutely superb.

Comment: @SolarMike Can you give a name of a book.

Comment: You have a name - search with that.